# Print using Stand Output in MEL

Tags: python, maya, mel

In Maya, with Python, I can write to the Command Response Window (I think it's called that - the single line window at the bottom right of the screen):

```
import sys

def console_it(s):
  sys.stdout.write(s)

console_it("Hello world")
```

What's the equivalent using MEL?

The following just prints to the Script editor History Window - which is not what I'm after.

```
global proc console_it(string $s)
{
    print($s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a direct equivalent for `sys.stdout.write(s)`.

But you could try a [warning](https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/commands/warning.html) command:

```
global proc console_it(string $s)
{
    warning $s;
}

console_it("Hello World")
```

P.S.

Or a [trace](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/trace.html) command, as @robthebloke suggested.

Comment: That works (on PC) however since it's a warning, the message appears on a yellow background with the //Warning: line X: prefix.

Comment: This is the only similar command that I could find.

Comment: trace might be what you're after?